# Sourcemap granularity

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I build a tool that does transformations to JavaScript Code. I want to provide a source map to the transformed code for debugging reasons.

I wonder at what granularity the source map is usually provided and if there are any standards or best practices.

E.g. `console.log("abc");`

Would it be useful to create a mapping for the dot, each single parenthesis, the semicolon, etc or maybe better to only map identifiers and arguments as a whole?